# Achieve 3D like scrollable stacked paginated list in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdLBW.png)

How to achieve  3d  like  scrollable stacked card in list  in flutter  like image mentioned above ..it should be scrollable ,can be paginated , to detect user interaction like tap, swipe ,is there any plugin available ? if  available please mention it.
using flutter version : 3.10.2 ,
Dart SDK version: 3.0.2,

I tried plugin like swiper card , appinio_swiper 2.0.3 , swipeable card , stacked list,another transform page view  . But none of these plugins not helped for my usecase.

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think , there is no plugin work for your use-case .....

Try this code , it will work ..... it works for me.

It will scrollable , can be paginated , detect user interaction , swipe and you can customize

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Home Page'),
        ),
        body: PerspectiveListView(
            visualizedItems: 3,
            itemExtent: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .40,
            initialIndex: 4,
            backItemsShadowColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            children: List.generate(10, (index) {
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: NetworkImage(
                          "https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png")),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  color: Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt())
                      .withOpacity(1.0),
                ),
              );
            })));
  }
}

class PerspectiveListView extends StatefulWidget {
  const PerspectiveListView({
    super.key,
    required this.children,
    required this.itemExtent,
    required this.visualizedItems,
    this.initialIndex = 0,
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
    this.onTapFrontItem,
    this.onChangeItem,
    this.backItemsShadowColor = Colors.black,
  });

  final List<Widget> children;
  final double? itemExtent;
  final int? visualizedItems;
  final int? initialIndex;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry? padding;
  final ValueChanged<int>? onTapFrontItem;
  final ValueChanged<int>? onChangeItem;
  final Color backItemsShadowColor;

  @override
  State<PerspectiveListView> createState() => _PerspectiveListViewState();
}

class _PerspectiveListViewState extends State<PerspectiveListView> {
  PageController? _pageController;
  double? _pagePercent;
  int? _currentIndex;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pageController = PageController(
        initialPage: widget.initialIndex!,
        viewportFraction: 1 / widget.visualizedItems!);
    _currentIndex = widget.initialIndex;
    _pagePercent = 0.0;
    _pageController!.addListener(_pageListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController!.removeListener(_pageListener);
    _pageController!.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _pageListener() {
    _currentIndex = _pageController!.page!.floor();
    _pagePercent = (_pageController!.page! - _currentIndex!).abs();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      final height = constraints.maxHeight;
      return Stack(children: [
        Padding(
          padding: widget.padding!,
          child: _PerspectiveItems(
            heightItem: widget.itemExtent!,
            currentIndex: _currentIndex!,
            children: widget.children,
            generateItems: widget.visualizedItems!,
            pagePercent: _pagePercent!,
          ),
        ),
        Positioned.fill(
            child: DecoratedBox(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        colors: [
              widget.backItemsShadowColor.withOpacity(.8),
              widget.backItemsShadowColor.withOpacity(0)
            ])))),
        PageView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            controller: _pageController!,
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            onPageChanged: (value) {
              if (widget.onChangeItem != null) {
                widget.onChangeItem!(value);
              }
            },
            itemCount: widget.children.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return const SizedBox();
            }),
        Positioned.fill(
            top: height - widget.itemExtent!,
            child: GestureDetector(onTap: () {
              if (widget.onTapFrontItem != null) {
                widget.onTapFrontItem!(_currentIndex!);
              }
            }))
      ]);
    });
  }
}

class _PerspectiveItems extends StatelessWidget {
  const _PerspectiveItems({
    super.key,
    required this.generateItems,
    required this.currentIndex,
    required this.heightItem,
    required this.pagePercent,
    required this.children,
  });
  final int generateItems;
  final int currentIndex;
  final double heightItem;
  final double pagePercent;
  final List<Widget> children;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      final height = constraints.maxHeight;
      return Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: List.generate(generateItems, (index) {
            final invertedIndex = (generateItems - 2) - index;
            final indexPlus = index + 1;
            final positionPercent = indexPlus / generateItems;
            final endPositionPercent = index / generateItems;
            return (currentIndex > invertedIndex)
                ? _TransformedItem(
                    child: children[currentIndex - (invertedIndex + 1)],
                    heightItem: heightItem,
                    factorChange: pagePercent,
                    scale: lerpDouble(.8, 1.0, positionPercent),
                    endScale: lerpDouble(.8, 1.0, endPositionPercent),
                    translateY: (height - heightItem) * positionPercent,
                    endTranslateY: (height - heightItem) * endPositionPercent,
                  )
                : const SizedBox();
          })
            ..add((currentIndex < (children.length - 1)
                ? _TransformedItem(
                    child: children[currentIndex + 1],
                    heightItem: heightItem,
                    factorChange: pagePercent,
                    translateY: height + 20,
                    endTranslateY: (height - heightItem))
                : const SizedBox()))
            ..insert(
                0,
                (currentIndex > (generateItems - 1)
                    ? _TransformedItem(
                        child: children[currentIndex - generateItems],
                        heightItem: heightItem,
                        factorChange: 1.0,
                        endScale: .78,
                      )
                    : const SizedBox())));
    });
  }
}

class _TransformedItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const _TransformedItem(
      {super.key,
      required this.child,
      required this.heightItem,
      required this.factorChange,
      this.scale = 1.0,
      this.endScale = 1.0,
      this.translateY = 0.0,
      this.endTranslateY = 0.0});
  final Widget child;
  final double heightItem;
  final double factorChange;
  final double? scale;
  final double? endScale;
  final double? translateY;
  final double? endTranslateY;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        transform: Matrix4.identity()
          ..scale(lerpDouble(scale, endScale, factorChange))
          ..translate(
              0.0, lerpDouble(translateY, endTranslateY, factorChange)!, 0.0),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: heightItem,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: child,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```